# Model relating reservoir releases with downstream temperature

Tags: temperature, numerical-modelling

Are there any statistical/numerical models developed relating release from reservoirs with the downstream river temperatures? I know of complicated hydrodynamic models such as CE-QUAL-W2 etc. but I am trying to know if someone has worked on specifically modeling the temperature with reservoir operations, in case such a relation exists.